# Fortran array of derived types and memory leaks despite finalization

Tags: memory-leaks, fortran, null-pointer, derived-types

I defined a derived type and encountered some problems with memory deallocation although I had written the final procedure. The code is as follows

```
module ModuleCoordinate
  implicit none

  type :: TCoordinate
    real(8),dimension(:),pointer :: Coordinate => NULL()
    contains
      procedure :: TCoordinateAssignment
      generic,public :: Assignment(=) => TCoordinateAssignment
      final :: TCoordinateDel
  end type TCoordinate

  interface TCoordinate
    module procedure :: TCoordinateInit
  end interface TCoordinate

  contains
    subroutine TCoordinateDel(self)
      type(TCoordinate),intent(inout) :: self
      if(associated(self%Coordinate))deallocate(self%Coordinate)
    end subroutine TCoordinateDel

    subroutine TCoordinateAssignment(O1,O2)
      class(TCoordinate),intent(out) :: O1
      type(TCoordinate),intent(in) :: O2
      if(associated(O2%Coordinate))allocate(O1%Coordinate,source=O2%Coordinate)
    end subroutine TCoordinateAssignment

    type(TCoordinate) function TCoordinateInit(IVal1,IVal2) result(self)
      real(8),intent(in) :: IVal1,IVal2
      allocate(self%Coordinate(2))
      self%Coordinate=(/IVal1,IVal2/)
    end function TCoordinateInit
end module ModuleCoordinate
```

The test code is as follows

```
program test
  implicit none
  integer(4),parameter :: NLoop=40000
  integer(4) :: i
  do i=1,NLoop
    call TestMemory1()
    call TestMemory2()
  end do
  pause
end program test

subroutine TestMemory1()
  use ModuleCoordinate
  implicit none
  integer(4),parameter :: DN=10
  integer(4) :: i
  type(TCoordinate),dimension(DN) :: a
  do i=1,DN
    a(i)=TCoordinate(1.0_8,1.0_8)
  end do
end subroutine TestMemory1

subroutine TestMemory2()
  use ModuleCoordinate
  implicit none
  type(TCoordinate) :: b1,b2,b3,b4,b5,b6,b7,b8,b9,b10
  b1=TCoordinate(1.0_8,1.0_8)
  b2=TCoordinate(1.0_8,1.0_8)
  b3=TCoordinate(1.0_8,1.0_8)
  b4=TCoordinate(1.0_8,1.0_8)
  b5=TCoordinate(1.0_8,1.0_8)
  b6=TCoordinate(1.0_8,1.0_8)
  b7=TCoordinate(1.0_8,1.0_8)
  b8=TCoordinate(1.0_8,1.0_8)
  b9=TCoordinate(1.0_8,1.0_8)
  b10=TCoordinate(1.0_8,1.0_8)
end subroutine TestMemory2
```

It turns out that the subroutine `TestMemory2` is OK while `TestMemory1` is not, which means that when an array of this derived type is declared the final procedure doesn't work and the memory leaks.

However, if I delete the `=> NULL()` on the right of the `Coordinate` in the definition of this derived type, both subroutines seem to work well.

What makes the difference when the pointer `Coordinate` is being deallocated?
 The complier is ifort_2013_sp1.3.174 if it matters.

Comment: Do you provide a final subroutine for arrays of that type?

Comment: No...I just added it and it does work. Thanks a lot. But it is still a little wired that deleting the "=> NULL()" alse works even if I forget the final procedure for arrays.

Answer (score 2):

In the description of the finalization process we see (Fortran 2008, 4.5.6.2)

> If the dynamic type of the entity has a final subroutine whose dummy argument has the same kind type parameters and rank as the entity being finalized, it is called with the entity as an actual argument. Otherwise, if there is an elemental final subroutine whose dummy argument has the same
>   kind type parameters as the entity being finalized, it is called with the entity as an actual argument. Otherwise, no subroutine is called at this point.

There is a final subroutine for the derived type provided only for scalar (rank-0) entities.  To have finalization for your rank-1 entity the simplest way (it seems, in this case) is to make the subroutine you have elemental.

I'm slightly reluctant to mention the `=>NULL()` aspect as I have no current means of testing what I'm about to write, but I'll speculate.

Without the `=>NULL()` default initialization the pointer component has undefined association status.  This means, that when you do

```
    b1=TCoordinate(1.0_8,1.0_8)
```

interesting things happen.

As part of the assignment `b1` is finalized on entry to `TCoordinateAssignment`.  The finalization involves calling `associated` with the pointer which is of undefined association status.  This is not allowed (with the consequence that any result could come about).

Comment: And as an aside: it's probably a good reminder to carefully consider allocatable components rather than pointer ones.