# Destruction of Array of Derived Type in Fortran

Tags: fortran, gfortran, intel-fortran, fortran2003

I get segmentation fault with the following code using gcc 5.2.0 and 6.1.0.

```
module a_module
  implicit none
  type :: a
     character(len=16) :: name = "none"
   contains
     final:: destroy_a
  end type a
contains
  subroutine destroy_a(this)
    type(a), intent(inout) :: this
    print *, "destroying a: ", this%name, loc(this)
  end subroutine destroy_a
end module a_module

module b_module
  use a_module
  implicit none
  type :: b
     character(len=16) :: name = "none"
     type(a) :: object_a
   contains
     final :: destroy_b
  end type b
contains
  subroutine destroy_b (this)
    type(b), intent(inout) :: this
    print *, "destroying b: ", this%name, loc(this)
  end subroutine destroy_b
end module b_module

module c_module
  use b_module
  implicit none
  type :: c
     character(len=16) :: name = "none"
     type(b) :: object_b(2)
   contains
     final :: destroy_c
  end type c
contains
  subroutine destroy_c(this)
    type(c), intent(inout) :: this
    print *, "destroying c: ", this%name, loc(this)
  end subroutine destroy_c
end module c_module

program main
  use c_module
  implicit none
  call f ()
contains
  subroutine f()
    type(c) :: x
    x%name = "object c"
    x%object_b(1)%name = "Object B(1)"
    x%object_b(1)%object_a%name = "object b(1)%a"
    x%object_b(2)%name = "object b(2)"
    x%object_b(2)%object_a%name = "object b(2)%a"
    print *, 'loc of c     ', loc(x)
    print *, 'loc of b(1)  ', loc(x%object_b(1))
    print *, 'loc of b(1)%a', loc(x%object_b(1)%object_a)
    print *, 'loc of b(2)  ', loc(x%object_b(2))
    print *, 'loc of b(2)%a', loc(x%object_b(2)%object_a)
  end subroutine f
end program main
```

The results I get are,

```
 loc of c           140733747692976
 loc of b(1)        140733747692992
 loc of b(1)%a      140733747693008
 loc of b(2)        140733747693024
 loc of b(2)%a      140733747693040
 destroying c: object c              140733747692976
 destroying a: object b(1)%a         140733747693008
Program received signal SIGSEGV: Segmentation fault - invalid memory
reference.
```

If I compile the code with Intel, it runs. But the results are not what I expected.

```
 loc of c            140737488319232
 loc of b(1)         140737488319248
 loc of b(1)%a       140737488319264
 loc of b(2)         140737488319280
 loc of b(2)%a       140737488319296
 destroying c: object c               140737488319232
 destroying a: object b(1)%a          140737488319264
 destroying a: object b(2)%a          140737488319296
```

Why is the destructor of type b not called?

Optimization is disabled in all these tests.

Comment: See [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28548581) about finalization of arrays.

Comment: @francescalus Yes, I meant to show `a_module`.  The question has been edited to add the missing code.

Comment: @francescalus I added `elemental` in front of `subroutine destroy_b` and removed the print statement inside.  I still got the same error. If I do that to `subroutine destroy_a` too, the code runs without error.  But I am not sure if any of the two subroutines actually gets called, because if I add `this%name="none"` to subroutines `destroy_a` and `destroy_b`, I get segfault again.

Comment: I can't comment on the segfaults with gfortran beyond: finalization is still fairly new in gfortran so it's quite possible unexpected crashes happen.

Comment: When providing an array form (having an array dummy will allow you to keep the printing which a pure elemental won't - you could try with `impure elemental`) does your expected behaviour with ifort come to pass?

Comment: @francescalus Thanks for your help! This appears to be a gfortran bug.  Using `impure elemental` and ifort, I can see the object destructors are called in the order of c, b(1), b(2), b(1)%a, and b(2)%a.  But with gfortran, if I only print the location of the object, I can see when `destroy_b` is called the second time, the `this` argument has the wrong address.

Comment: Updates: If allocatable array of b is used instead of automatic array, gfortran works even without `impure elemental`.

Comment: I'll propose this as a duplicate of that other question.  There are, though, two questions here: what is wrong with this code (that's the array final subroutine answer)?; why does gfortran crash?  The first is the more useful to address in many ways: even without a crash the result would be wrong.

Comment: You are right.  I meant as explicit shape array component of c.

Comment: I closed it as a duplicate. If there are reasons for reopening just comment.

Comment: If there is a bug in gfortran it should be reported at https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/enter_bug.cgi?product=gcc