# Fortran finalization subroutine does not work when type is an array

Tags: arrays, fortran, finalization

Recently I found a serious problem that is in some cases finalization function does not work.

Description:

I defined a type, say `TYPE(testtype):: T`, in which many pointers and allocatable arrays being used. And there is a finalization subroutine, say `final:: de`. This function (`de`) works fine (I put write in it to check that). However, when I define an array  `TYPE(testtype),allocatable::T(:)`, after I finish using it, function `de` is not called when I `deallocate(T)`. Here I put on the testing code. As one can check, `subdo1()` is working well( output `"work"`), while final in `subdo2()` is failed.

```
    module test1
        implicit none
        !--------------
        type testtype
          real(8)::x
        contains
          final::de
        end type
        !--------------
        contains
        subroutine de(self)
            type(testtype)::self
            write(*,*)"work"
        end subroutine
    end module

    subroutine subdo1()
        use test1
        implicit none
        class(testtype),pointer::t
        allocate(t)
        deallocate(t)
    end subroutine

    subroutine subdo2()
        use test1
        implicit none
        class(testtype),pointer::t(:)
        allocate(t(2))
        deallocate(t)
    end subroutine

    program test
        implicit none
        !call subdo1()
        call subdo2()
    end program
```

I tried both gfortran and ifort (ifort version 17.0.0)

Comment: Please avoid writing "it does not work" because it does not mean anything specific. Say that iit is not called (in your example), that there is an error message, that the resolts are wrong or anything which will tell us the details.

Comment: In addition to the duplicate link see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43282482/does-the-finalization-routine-need-to-be-elemental-in-order-to-be-called-on-the?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Thank you so much!~